# xorg not working

Tags: arch-linux, xorg

Yesterday, my xorg was working but it was using integrated graphics. I tried to get nvidia working. Now, when I run `startx`, I get a screen on tty3 which shows the output of the last tty I was in. For example, I hit ctrl+alt+f1, type `startx` and am moved to tty3 where I get a black screen with a solid cursor. If I go back to tty0 I can see the output of startx which shows no errors (besides minor gtk css warning) and a blinking cursor. When I go back to tty3, I see the same thing with a solid cursor.

Info:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.8.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 15 10:14:30 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`.xinitrc`:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

conky &
exec startxfce4
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  1743.684] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[  1743.684] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1743.684] Build Operating System: Linux 4.5.4-1-ARCH x86_64 
[  1743.684] Current Operating System: Linux Hermes 4.8.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 10 17:22:48 CET 2016 x86_64
[  1743.684] Kernel command line: \vmlinuz-linux ro root=UUID=1d746b96-3184-49ac-a204-0f9deda59c87 pci=nomsi initrd=\initramfs-linux.img
[  1743.684] Build Date: 19 July 2016  05:54:24PM
[  1743.684]  
[  1743.684] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  1743.684]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1743.684] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1743.684] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Nov 15 10:24:19 2016
[  1743.684] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  1743.684] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1743.684] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  1743.684] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  1743.684] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1743.684] (==) No device specified for screen "Screen0".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  1743.684] (**) |   |-->Device "DiscreteNvidia"
[  1743.684] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Screen0".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1743.684] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[  1743.684] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[  1743.684] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1743.684] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1743.684] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1743.684] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1743.684] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[  1743.684]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1743.684] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/
[  1743.684] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1743.684] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  1743.684] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  1743.684] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  1743.684] (II) Loader magic: 0x821d40
[  1743.684] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1743.684]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1743.684]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[  1743.684]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[  1743.684]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[  1743.685] (--) using VT number 7

[  1743.685] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  1743.686] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[  1743.686] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1743.704] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:191b:1462:115a rev 6, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1743.704] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:139b:1462:115a rev 162, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  1743.704] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1743.704] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1743.705] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1743.710] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1743.710]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.710]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1743.710] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.10  Fri Oct 14 10:01:22 PDT 2016
[  1743.710] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1743.710] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  1743.710] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1743.710]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.710]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1743.710] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  375.10  Fri Oct 14 09:38:17 PDT 2016
[  1743.710] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  1743.739] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1743.739] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1743.739] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1743.739] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1743.739]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.739]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1743.739] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[  1743.739] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[  1743.739] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[  1743.739] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1743.739]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1743.739]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1743.739] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[  1743.739] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[  1743.739] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[  1743.740] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1743.740] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[  1743.740] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1743.740] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1743.740] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 960M (GM107-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[  1744.067] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[  1744.067] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 82.07.94.00.0e
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
[  1744.067] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[  1744.067] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[  1744.067] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[  1744.067] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  1744.068] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[  1744.068] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[  1744.071] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[  1744.088] (II) NVIDIA(0): Built-in logo is bigger than the screen.
[  1744.088] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1744.092] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[  1744.092] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[  1744.092] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[  1744.093] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[  1744.093] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[  1744.093] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1744.093] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[  1744.093] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[  1744.093] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[  1744.093] (--) RandR disabled
[  1744.095] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[  1744.095] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[  1744.145] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[  1744.145] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.145] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.145] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.145] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[  1744.146] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1744.146]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.22.0
[  1744.146]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1744.146]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[  1744.146] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1744.146] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1744.146] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[  1744.146] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.146] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.146] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[  1744.163] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input5/event4"
[  1744.163] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  1744.163] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.163] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[  1744.163] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event7)
[  1744.163] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.163] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.163] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[  1744.163] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[  1744.163] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[  1744.163] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.164] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.164] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[  1744.186] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9/event7"
[  1744.186] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  1744.187] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.187] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[  1744.187] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event8)
[  1744.187] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.187] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.187] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[  1744.187] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[  1744.187] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[  1744.187] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.188] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.188] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is a keyboard
[  1744.203] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:12/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input10/event8"
[  1744.203] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  1744.204] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.204] (II) input device 'Video Bus', /dev/input/event8 is a keyboard
[  1744.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[  1744.205] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.205] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[  1744.205] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.205] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.205] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1744.205] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1744.205] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1744.205] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.206] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.206] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1744.223] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input4/event3"
[  1744.223] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[  1744.224] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.224] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1744.224] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event2)
[  1744.225] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.225] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.225] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[  1744.225] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[  1744.225] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[  1744.225] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.225] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.225] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[  1744.243] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input3/event2"
[  1744.243] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[  1744.244] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.244] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[  1744.246] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M325 (/dev/input/event9)
[  1744.246] (**) Logitech M325: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  1744.246] (**) Logitech M325: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  1744.246] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech M325'
[  1744.246] (**) Logitech M325: always reports core events
[  1744.246] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[  1744.246] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.246] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1744.247] (II) Device 'Logitech M325' set to 600 DPI
[  1744.247] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is a pointer caps
[  1744.293] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0004/0003:046D:400A.0005/input/input11/event9"
[  1744.293] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech M325" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[  1744.293] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1744.293] (**) Logitech M325: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1744.293] (**) Logitech M325: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1744.293] (**) Logitech M325: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1744.294] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1744.294] (II) Device 'Logitech M325' set to 600 DPI
[  1744.294] (II) input device 'Logitech M325', /dev/input/event9 is a pointer caps
[  1744.295] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M325 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  1744.295] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.295] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.296] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[  1744.296] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.296] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.296] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event12)
[  1744.296] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.296] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.297] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[  1744.297] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.297] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.297] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[  1744.297] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.297] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.298] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[  1744.298] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.298] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.299] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[  1744.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.299] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[  1744.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[  1744.299] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[  1744.299] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.299] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.299] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[  1744.343] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[  1744.343] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  1744.344] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.344] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[  1744.345] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event10)
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[  1744.345] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[  1744.345] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[  1744.345] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1744.345]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.8.99
[  1744.345]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1744.345]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[  1744.345] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[  1744.345] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1744.345] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[  1744.383] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: ignoring touch events for semi-multitouch device
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5706 (res 44)
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4800 (res 65)
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[  1744.383] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  1744.383] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1744.423] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7/event10"
[  1744.423] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[  1744.423] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[  1744.423] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[  1744.423] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.037
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1744.423] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1744.423] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  1744.424] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[  1744.424] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[  1744.425] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[  1744.425] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1744.425] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1744.426] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSI WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[  1744.426] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1744.426] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1744.426] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MSI WMI hotkeys'
[  1744.426] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[  1744.426] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[  1744.426] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1744.426] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.426] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[  1744.443] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input8/event6"
[  1744.443] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MSI WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[  1744.444] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1744.444] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.708] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.709] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  1744.736] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
[  1744.807] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.10  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-09)  Fri Oct 14 11:11:07 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

#Section "Files"
#EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
   Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
#    VendorName     "Unknown"
#    ModelName      "Unknown"
#    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
#    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
#    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960M"
    BusID      "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
       Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

## Welcome to the Nvidia vs. Linux war!

1- First off purge all Nvidia drivers:

- `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

2- Next, reconfigure your xorg:

- Make a copy and save it in a safe place >this file> /etc/X11/xorg.conf. If things go wrong you might need it later again:

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BACKUP`

The next steps will reconfigure your xorg and install nouveau drivers(intel GPU)

`sudo apt-get install nouveau-firmware`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

**Now to get Nvidia on your Linux system you need BumbleBee!**

Comment: I am using arch. I don't have apt. Do you know the equivalent commands? Is there really no way to use nvidia drivers? I have to use my integrated gpu? I have had success before with nvidia drivers.

Comment: My bad I assumed you had Ubuntu. Try this and see `pacman -Ss xf86-video`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nouveau

Comment: Nvidia gave me a headache back in the day on Ubuntu. If you still want to use them check out http://bumblebee-project.org . The only way to get them running without errors.